# How to run pipelines manually as well as automatically for some cases in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd been checking Gitlab workflows and currently have similar setup:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
```

This lets me trigger pipelines automatically as well as manually. However, I'd like to have the jobs manually triggerable as well as automatically started under some circumstances such as:

- When PR merged to master
- Manually triggered

I've tried to use when: manual flag under workflow#rules but It wasn't a valid configuration according to Gitlab.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The Full setup is as below:

```
image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"

services:
  - mysql:latest


connect:
  stage: test
  image: mysql
  script:
    - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"


stages:
  - test
  - release

test:
  script:
    - sbt scalafmtCheckAll test-ci
    - sbt it:test

docker:image:
  stage: release
  image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"
  

  script:
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: `when: manual` is not valid for `workflows`. You can use `when` for [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) at job level, it will allow to set `when: manual` to run job manually

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I cannot make it work, how would it look like in this setup? I'll update the question with my full setup.

Comment: Hi, I posted example, hope it will help. If not let me know :)

Comment: Not exactly but made it work eventually, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you would like to run manual job for release stage, then your `docker:image` section would look like this one:

```yaml
docker:image:
  stage: release
  image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.6_1.3.10_2.11.12"  
  script:
    - sbt docker:publishLocal
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
      when: manual
```

All jobs should start automatically and only `docker:image` should runs only on manual action